# Pass Record ID in current view to foreign key in Related Create view ASP.NET MVC using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multiple tables that are all linked with foreign keys in my model. I want to be able to pass the ID of the current record into another view as a foreign key automatically but am failing.

```
public partial class Update
{
    public int UpdateID { get; set; }
    public int UpdateTypeID { get; set; }
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public string UpdateDetails { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public string Updated_By { get; set; }

    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
    public virtual UpdateType UpdateType { get; set; }
}
```

My create  method for Update looks like this;

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="UpdateID,UpdateTypeID,UpdateDetails,DateUpdated,Updated_By")] int RequestID, Update update)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Updates.Add(update);
            update.DateUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            update.Updated_By = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index","Request");
        }


        //ViewBag.RequestID = new SelectList(db.Requests, "RequestID", "CustName", update.RequestID);
        ViewBag.UpdateTypeID = new SelectList(db.UpdateTypes, "UpdateTypeID", "UpdateTypeName", update.UpdateTypeID);
        return View(update);
    }
```

And the view where i want the data to be passed is;

```
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID, "Request", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model =>model.RequestID)
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to automatically insert the correct RequestID, So, if the Request DetailsView has a link to the Create Update view, how do I tell the Create Update method that the RequestID for it is the one that the link came from?

Comment: What is the error? If you have one?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'RequestID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(Int32, HelpDeskApp.Models.Update)' in 'HelpDeskApp.Controllers.UpdateController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters